# Dreamweaver error warning

Tags: php, include, dreamweaver

Why does Dreamweaver flag this as an error and gives me the warning

"Special characters must be escaped: [<]"

when it finds this

```
<?php include("nav_none.php"); ?>
```

in the source code?

Thanks,

Kirk

Comment: Presumably because that is inside an element that is supposed to contain text.  That is not valid HTML.  (And doesn't make sense in an HTML document ... except as text, where HTML says that you must represent a `<` with a `&lt;` for instance.)

Comment: But if you are trying to use Dreamweaver to edit a PHP file, then read this: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/323078-how-to-embed-or-integrate-php-page-into-html-in-dreamweaver/

Comment: That's kind of what I figured but you'd think Dreamweaver would know about the syntax for a php include, wouldn't you?

Comment: Well, a PHP include is only valid in a PHP file.  If you use ".htm" as the file suffix, you have told DreamWeaver that you are editing an HTML document.  In that context, a PHP include is meaningless.  It would be wrong to "understand" a PHP include if it was a meaningless construct.  The correct thing for DreamWeaver to do is to assume that you have made a mistake.

Comment: I never knew that about the difference between htm and html. Thanks. I guess I have a LOT to learn.

Comment: I just saved it as htm but it still shows the error.

Comment: You misunderstood.  ".htm" and ".html" mean the same thing.  If you want DreamWeaver to understand the file as a PHP file, you need a ".php" suffix.

Comment: Now you can see how hopelessly ignorant I am. But I still think that DW should know that php includes show up in html documents, as in my case, and should not flag it as an error.

Comment: PHP includes should >>never<< show up an HTML document.  Why?  Because a complaint HTML document parser has no idea what to do with it.  What you have there is a PHP file, plain and simple.  It should have ".php" suffix.

Comment: My wife/partner does something to the htaccess file that make html docs behave like php docs ... or at least I think that's what she does. She's much more savvy than me.

Comment: Yes.  But that is a server-side trick.  Dreamweaver has no way of knowing you are going to do that.  Anyhow, the fact remains that Dreamweaver is behaving correctly, and if you want it to know that those ".htm" / ".html" files are actually PHP source files, you will need to change the file suffixes ... to what they ought to be for PHP files.

Comment: Thanks, Stephen. I've learned something new and that's good. Merry Christmas.

Answer (score 0):

i know its very late to reply you but am doing this for you and other people. This happens when you type properties of any tag without spaces or you misses simple syntax error like writing = or column sign. In your case i am pretty sure that you must be writing   in file that has html file type extension. When you do same with .php type file extension you will not get any warning message.

I am here demonstrating few common html syntax errors that we makes every time when we write html codes.

```
<a href="img/Accolade1a.JPG">
 <img src="img/Accolade1a.JPG" alt"">
 <p>Accolade1a Template</p>
</a>
```

Here on the line number 2 from the top at alt attribute = sign is missing, however this will work but most of the smart browser will give you warning to correct this. Below is correction:

```
<a href="img/Accolade1a.JPG">
 <img src="img/Accolade1a.JPG" alt="">
 <p>Accolade1a Template</p>
</a>
```

And another common problem is not providing spaces between attributes of tag. This is just typo error. it will work on most of the browsers but it spoils readability of code. Please have a look

```
<div class="form-group"style="color:#fff;">
 </div>
```

and correction of this warning is just put white space after " and warning will get lost. have a look:

```
 <div class="form-group" style="color:#fff;">
     </div>
```

So try to write good code it will help you a lot. Trust me Dreamweaver is very good software from Adobe.
I hope it will helpful to you.