# dreamweaver <?php & ?> special characters must be escaped error

Tags: php, dreamweaver

I've hunted around everywhere for this error fix, but no luck.

Using Dreamweaver, when i put the PHP code bracketing into an html file such as `<?php echo 'Why does it not work?'; ?>` or something similar, I always get an error "Special characters must be escaped".  I can't stand it anymore!

Any help would be soooo much appreciated.  I've tried to change the code type at the bottom so it recognises it as PHP and doesn't give me grief about the brackets, but nothing.

I've modified the .htaccess file on the server so I've got no problems running php code in a html file.

Comment: which version of Dreamweaver?

Comment: It's the 2017 version

Comment: So this is an error that comes up on the site or in the application itself??

Comment: [The comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348109/dreamweaver-error-warning) pretty much tell you what you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

- Go to Edit -> Preferences
- in left panel highlight linting
- then in edit rule set highlight html, click edit and apply changes, scroll down to where it says 
  `"spec-char-escape": true`, and change it to `false`, edit your page
- click save

You should no longer see errors

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd put the answer here in case anyone else has a similar problem.  The validation I was talking about is called "linting" in DW.  I edited the linting HTML file from inside DW: Edit > Preferences > Linting > Select code type then Edit & Apply changes.  In my case I set escape special characters to false in the file.  Voila!

Here's the linting specs: https://github.com/yaniswang/HTMLHint/wiki/Rules